# git clone does not compile (undefined symbol _clock_gettime_nsec_np) Google VR SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, google-vr-sdk

I am getting below error after pod update in Google VR Sdk

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "_clock_gettime_nsec_np", referenced from:
>
> base::GetCurrentTimeNanos() in libGVRSDK.a(get_current_time.o)
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Xcode 7.3, when I switched to Xcode 8 and above version, issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the GVR-iOS-SDK GitHub repo doesn't contain the libGVRSDK.a. You shouldn't use this repo - just use CocoaPods and it will work just fine!